# table sorter pager not working with multiple tables in page. Only 1st 10 item visible

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tablesorter

Hi I am using table sorter with bootstrap 3
The url for the plugin is 
http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/

Everything is ok when there is only one table in page. I have done it reading after 
http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-bootstrap-theme.html

like $("table").tablesorter({......})

But when there are several tables with in same page, The pager doesnt work. The arrows are disabled and its strange that only the first 10 items are visible. It seems tablesorter activates as the sorting works but paging not works.

No arrows are working.When I keep only one table. it works fine.
I tried everything so far but failed. Can anyone help.

Thank You!

Comment: Please provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing an example of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think I answered your question in the [tablesorter issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/478). Basically, make sure that each pager has a unique name for its specified table.

```
<table class="table1">...<table>
<div class="pager1">...</div>

<table class="table2">...<table>
<div class="pager2">...</div>
```

then initialize each table separately

```
$(".table1").tablesorter().tablesorterPager({ container: '.pager1' });
$(".table2").tablesorter().tablesorterPager({ container: '.pager2' });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struck in the same issue, and since I'm always concerned about being as generic as possible, I made this simple code that gives IDs to tables, numbered as they appear in the code, and apply the specific pager to each of them.

**JS**

```
  $(".tablesorter table").each(function(pageTableCount){

    // Check if pageTableCount was initialized, and add 1 to its value
    pageTableCount !==null ? pageTableCount++ : 1;

    // Get the table and add ID with counter
    table = $(this);
    table.attr("id","table-sorter-"+pageTableCount);

    // Does the same with the pager
    pager = table.parent().find(".tablesorter-pager");
    pager.attr("id","table-sorter-pager-"+pageTableCount);

    // Initiate the tablesorter
    table.tablesorter()
    .tablesorterPager({
      container: "#table-sorter-pager-"+pageTableCount
    });

  });
```

**HTML ( BS + FontAwesome)**

```
        <div class="table-responsive tablesorter">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                ...
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

              <tr>
                ...
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class="tablesorter-pager">
            <a href="#" class="first btn btn-default btn-sm btn-icon"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="prev btn btn-default btn-sm btn-icon"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
            <span class="pagedisplay"></span>
            <a href="#" class="next btn btn-default btn-sm btn-icon"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="last btn btn-default btn-sm btn-icon"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
          </div><!-- tablesorter-pager -->
        </div><!-- .table-responsive -->
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can multiple tables in one using table sorter. Please refer this.
http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/table-pagination/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.